# Custom navigation bar via wp_list_pages is broken for blog roll

Tags: navigation, blog, wp-list-pages

Pretty simple question.

I have the 'blog' on my site set via 'reading' to be the page 'blog' located at mysite.com/blog. `/blog` is hierarchical, in that it has children.

I have a custom side bar that I include via a function in `functions.php` that does a simple include (ie: `function get_right_sidebar() { include('sidebar_right.php) };` ). I list all pages and children via a simple function:

```
function get_post_top_ancestor_id(){
    global $post;

     if($post->post_parent){
        $ancestors = array_reverse(get_post_ancestors($post->ID));
        return $ancestors[0];
    }

     return $post->ID;
}
```

Followed by:

```
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <?php wp_list_pages( array('title_li'=>'','include'=>get_post_top_ancestor_id()) ); ?>
        <?php wp_list_pages( array('title_li'=>'','depth'=>1,'child_of'=>get_post_top_ancestor_id()) ); ?>
    </ul>
```

In the actual page template `sidebar_right.php`

Now, this navigation bar works completely fine, accept when I navigate to the base-level `/blog`. Nothing shows up in the sidebar.

After doing a `global $post; print_r($post)`in the `sidebar_right.php` I see that it is listing a post as the query, instead of page (and therefore is not getting the child pages to list in the sidebar).

I tried tossing in a `wp_reset_query`, but it did nothing.

Can anyone recommend what I should do in order to restore my navigation bar on my `/blog` section?

Thanks!

Tre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem when you set a 'page' as the blog roll through the back-end is that it automatically assigns the page as an 'archive'.

In order to solve the problem, I removed this option (ie: set blog roll to --Select--). I set the page to it's own custom template and made a custom query feed, so I could utilize `wp_reset_query()`. This then restored the functionality and my right sidebar navigation.